# How can I check if the result of a division is an integer in C?

Tags: c, math, integer, division

I need to check if the result of a mathematical division is an integer or not.

For example, 8 / 2 = 4 
is ok.
but 5 / 2 = 2.5 
shouldn't be ok.

I've tried the following:

```
bool isPrime(int num) 
{
    /* Checks all the numbers before the given input. If the result of 
    dividing 
    the input by one of those numbers is an int, then the input is not a 
    prime number. */
    int i, check;
    double result;
    for (i=2; i<num; i++) {
        result = (double) num / i;
        check = (int) result;
        if (isdigit(check))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm having nightmares about `isdigit` and how to insert the parameter in the right way. I know it requires an `int`, but I have a `double`, so I can't really put those pieces together.

Comment: `isdigit` is about characters, not numbers, so it doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: check the remainder after division using the `%` (*modulus*) operator: `if (num % i == 0) /* num is a multiple of i --or-- num/i is an integer */;`

Comment: Please show the entire function.

Comment: For prime hunting, you don't need to search up to N-1; up to and including
`ceil(sqrt(N))` is sufficient.
If N is composite, then one factor is not larger than √N and the other
is not smaller than √N).
After you've checked for 'divisible by 2', you could check only the odd
numbers.
If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger
primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer K starting at K equal to 1.
Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when N is just in
the thousands, let alone much bigger.
Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to do something like this:

```
result = (double) num / i;
check = (int) result;
if(check == result) {
    ...
```

Logically, this is correct. But it will not work in practice because floats does not have infinite precision.

The proper way to check divisibility is using the modulo operator:

```
if(num % i == 0) {
    // Code to run if num / i is an integer
```

Comment: @NateEldredge: there was no type for `num` in the original posting and the OP mentioned the `double` type. But the use case was pretty obvious. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand the logic of your function. But maybe this help you. Compare the result of the `%` modulo operation by the result of the division with the floored version of the division´s result, to `0`. If it equals `0`, `return true;`, if not `return false;`.

At `long long int res_floored = res;` happens an implicit conversion from `double` to `long long int` - The value gets floored, f.e. `4.7` to `4`. No explicit cast is needed.

Before that, we have to check if the floored `double` value of the result of the division is capable to be hold in an `long long int`. Therefore, I compare `res` to the macros `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_INT`, header `limits.h`, which represent the maximum and minimum integral values a `long int` can hold.  If it doens´t fit we `return -1;` as error.

```
int div_result_in_int (double dividend, double divisor);
{
    double res = dividend / divisor;

    if (res > LONG_MAX || res < LONG_MIN)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    long long int res_floored = res;

    if (res % res_floored == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I use `double` for both parameters, because the division of two floating-point values can result in an integral value.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

int div_result_in_int (double dividend, double divisor)
{
    double res = dividend / divisor;

    if (res > LONG_MAX || res < LONG_MIN)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    long long int res_floored = res;

    if (res == res_floored)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", div_result_in_int(8,4));
    printf("%d\n", div_result_in_int(9,5));
    printf("%d\n", div_result_in_int(3,1));
    printf("%d\n", div_result_in_int(97,14));
    printf("%d\n", div_result_in_int(2,0.5));
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: This does not work if `res` exceeds the range of `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie Better now?

Comment: Technically not: it still does not work if `res` exceeds the range of `long long int`.

Comment: The question is ambiguous: does the OP want to test if the result is an integer or if it fits in type `int` or some other integer type?

Comment: Actually, the OP is using integer arithmetic for a prime number test, the floating point arithmetics is off topic :(

Comment: @chqrlie I implemented a security guard.

Comment: @chqrlie Hmm :-/ I let my answer alive for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test if an integer division has no remainder: use the modulo operator `%` that computes the remainder.  The `isdigit()` function has a different purpose: it tests whether a byte read by `getc()` is a digit (`'0'` to `'9'`) or not.

Here is a modified version:

```c
bool isPrime(int num) {
    /* Checks all the numbers before the given input. If the result of 
       dividing the input by one of those numbers is integer, then the
       input is not a prime number. */
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that it would be much quicker for prime numbers to stop the search when `i * i > num`:

```c
bool isPrime(int num) {
    /* Checks all the numbers before the given input. If the result of 
       dividing the input by one of those numbers is integer, then the
       input is not a prime number. */
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```